# Facebook flash game client-server communication

Tags: flash, facebook, sockets, networking, communication

We're currently working on a small scale indie card game for Facebook, which we hope will reach hundreds of thousands of players (eventually).

We have most of the issues figured out (scalability, server-side architecture, etc) - however one question - communication between client & server.

We have the following requirements:

- Server side push messages (no client message request)
- High scalability (should support at first hundreds and later hopefully thousands of CCUs)
- Secure, reliable layer
- Work well with most computers, routers & browsers
- Works with Adobe Flash/AS3

First thing that came to mind was socket connections, but I was wondering, is there a better solution that answers our needs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A socket connection is almost inevitable (see [transport layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer)).

A good idea is to use TCP: it guarantees delivery (high reliability), it's "connection" orientated. There are some downsides, but other alternatives are not available on most computers, routers and browsers.

A more important question is: what are you going to send over TCP? Generally, it's a good idea to use something that can be used in Flash and your server (see [Remote Procedure Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) for example).

"Push" messages are generally only a problem with HTTP connections, as it was designed to handle synchronous requests. However, in Flash you do not have this limitation.

Security can be added by "wrapping" a TCP connection: use SSL or TLS.

- XML serialization (XML-RPC): easy to develop and maintain, moderate performance, maybe reliable.
- RTMP ([Real Time Messaging Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)): native to Flash, great performance, great for realtime games, and can be tunneled over HTTP (to surpass any firewall/router).

See [NetConnection](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html) class, and the [Action Message Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format).

> The Adobe Integrated Runtime and Adobe Flash Player use AMF to communicate between an application and a remote server. AMF encodes remote procedure calls (RPC) into a compact binary representation that can be transferred over HTTP/HTTPS or the RTMP/RTMPS protocol. Objects and data values are serialized into this binary format, which increases performance, allowing applications to load data up to 10 times faster than with text-based formats such as XML or SOAP.

(from http://www.pyamf.org/)

Answer (score 1):

We use [WebORB](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/) in our flash games for comunicating serverside and clientside but i don't know it is enough for your requirements.

Sorry if i miss understood.

Comment: Note that WebORB uses AMF under the hood.